# Suspend mode - power light not blinking/flashing any more - Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: suspend, power-management, wakeonlan

Up until a few weeks ago, when I entered Suspend mode (pressing power button, selecting it from the power button dropdown  or automatic suspension), the power button on my tower would do a slow blink (about 1 per second).

Not sure what happened, but that no longer is the case.  Does anyone know why?  I have tried editing the grub file to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"` or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=shallow"` and it doesn't make a difference.

What would have changed this behaviour?  I have not made other changes to this computer and there are not a lot of fine controls of power settings that I have been able to find.

Comment: Has the LED died?

Comment: If you go back to an earlier kernel (during boot by selecting "Advanced Options" and then selecting from the list) does the LED functionality return?

Comment: LED is working fine, nice solid blue when powered up

Comment: Having trouble getting to Advanced Options, not recognizing SHIFT or ESC key presses on boot.  Will keep trying.

Comment: Can't seem to get to Advanced options on startup, but I used Grub Customizer to book to one kernel version back (5.0.0-20) and I have the same issue still.  Don't know if I can access other kernels further back - I wish I could force the Grub menu at startup so I could get to see more Advanced Options potentially.

Comment: You aren't alone. Since 2010 there are 500 votes for question and answer on how to show grub menu on boot up: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Comment: `5.0.0-19`or even `5.0.0-18` would be the kernel version a few weeks back. I think `5.0.0-20` is probably a couple weeks old.

Comment: thanks so much @WinEunuuchs2Unix - that link made me notice the option in Grub Customizer to set the "Boot default entry" time so that I could catch the menu!!

Bad news, only 5.0.0-20 and 21 are available there.  Now to research how to get back to older kernels...

Comment: @PeterEliopoulos I just stick to a Long Time Kernel chain that works `4.14 LTS`. I just install bug fixes for `4.14.134` a couple days ago: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165

Comment: 0k, I tried 5.0.0-19, 17 and 16 as well as the 4.14.134, no difference, no blinking in suspend mode (pushing the button or from the menu). Very odd.  I'm going to try a liveUSB version of 18.04 next.

Comment: It's now getting odd, 18.04 on a live USB has the same symptoms.  I'm convinced this is now some sort of hardware issue on the motherboard.